# Search through all folders recursively and find folder with the most files non-recursively

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

We have very matured file directory structure with an unknown depth.
I would like to find the folder with the most files in it's root, preferably only PDF, DOC|DOCX, XLS|XLSX and PPTX|PPTS.

I have tried this

```
$files=@{}
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\' -Recurse -Directory -ErrorAction Ignore | Foreach {
    $files[$_.Fullname] = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Recurse -File -ErrorAction Ignore).Count
} 
$files.GetEnumerator() | Sort Value -Descending -Top 1
```

from here https://superuser.com/a/970504/1252486
but it sums the file count recursively.

If I have this sample dir structure:

```
D:Tree
├───Dir1
│   │   File1.pdf
│   │   File2.pdf
│   │   File3.pdf
│   │
│   ├───Subdir1
│   │       Subfile1.pdf
│   │       Subfile2.pdf
│   │
│   └───Subdir2
│       │   Subfile1.pdf
│       │   Subfile2.pdf
│       │   Subfile3.pdf
│       │   Subfile4.pdf
│       │
│       └───Subsubdir1
│               Subsubfile1.pdf
│
├───Dir2
│   │   File1.pdf
│   │   File2.pdf
│   │   File3.pdf
│   │
│   ├───Subdir1
│   │       Subfile1.pdf
│   │       Subfile2.pdf
│   │       Subfile3.pdf
│   │
│   ├───Subdir2
│   │       Subfile1.pdf
│   │       Subfile2.pdf
│   │       Subfile3.pdf
│   │
│   └───Subdir3
│           Subfile1.pdf
│           Subfile2.pdf
│           Subfile3.pdf
│
└───Dir3
```

Tree\Dir2 has overall 12 Files, but only 3 files in it's root.
Tree\Dir1\Subdir2 would here be the target.

Is there a neat short snippet for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Based on [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object)**

```
Get-ChildItem D:\ -File -Recurse -Include *.pdf, *.doc |
    Group-Object DirectoryName | Sort-Object -Descending Count
```

**Based on a [`hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable)**

```
$Count = @{}
Get-ChildItem D:\ -File -Recurse -Include *.pdf, *.doc |
    Foreach-Object { $Count[$_.DirectoryName]++ }
$Count.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Descending Value
```

Comment: Group-Object is not common cmdlet, at least for me. Thanks. It's easier than creating a hashtable and better than [what GPT4 hallucinated](https://www.phind.com/search?cache=qvgmusr0unry15fwbys9g18i).

Comment: Short update: Your snippet is good and what I imagined. My idea to let it run on the company network share with multiple millions of files is bad.

Comment: @Synertry, not sure what you mean with "*Group-Object is not common cmdlet, at least for me*" (afaik, [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) is standard available in both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core). Anyways, I have added a version based on a hashtable as well. Although, I suspect that this version is a little faster, it can't be written as a oneliner (as a single pipeline statement)